# NodeJs Route returns 404 in production but not in local

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I'm working on my first NodeJS app.
I've try my application in local environment and it works well. So I decided to deploy it on my shared hosting.

I have an issue with a router that returns me a 404 in production environment but not in local.

Route I called: GET /match/getAllMatches

Here is my app.js file:

```
    const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const sequelize = require('./config/database');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const matchRouter = require('./routes/match.js');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/match', matchRouter);
app.use('/api/auth', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    });

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

module.exports = app;
```

Here is my match.js router file:

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('../controllers/match');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

router.get('/getAllMatches', controller.getAllMatches);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my small controller file:

```
const Event = require('../models/Event')

exports.createMatch = (req, res, next) => {
    delete req.body.id;
    const Event = new Event(...req.body);
    Event.save()
        .then(() => res.status(200).json({
            message:'Match créé avec succès'
        }))
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ error : error }));
};

exports.getAllMatches = (req, res, next) => {
    Event.findAll()
        .then((events) => {
            res.status(200).json(events);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.status(400).json({ error : error });
        })
};
```

Do you see something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score -1):

if you put **app.use("/")** before all of your routes then **how can any other route going to work**.

Comment: That not the problem when u use app.use("/", someRoutes)
Its just a prefix to all the imported routes from "someRoutes"

Comment: Indeed that's not the issue. Thanks for trying to help me ;)